# Calcular media vecinos matriz

Tags: c#

tengo creada la siguiente matriz rellenada con números aleatorios [8-20]:

```
int array[5000][2000];
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 2000; y++)
            array[x][y] = rand() % 13 + 8;
    };
```

Tengo que recorrer la matriz completa, e ir calculando la media de los vecinos de cada posición de la matriz, como se ve en la imagen, calcular la media de los 8 vecinos, y comparar finalmente el valor de la media no entera con el valor que tiene la posición actual.

He actualizado el código, tengo los bucles para recorrer la matriz, inicio los contadores y comparo con los 8 vecinos. Tengo que comparar el valor de la matriz con la media que es de tipo float, tengo que hacer un cast, pero me sigue dando error, esa es la única duda **actualmente**.

Gracias por la ayuda.
[image: Imagen]

```
int igual = 0; //Contadores
    int mayor = 0;
    int menor = 0;
    float media = 0;

    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < 5000; iColumn++)
    {
        for (int jRow = 0; jRow < 2000; jRow++)
        {

            media = matriz[jRow-1, iColumn-1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow , iColumn - 1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow-1, iColumn];
            media =+ matriz[jRow-1, iColumn+1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow, iColumn+1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow+1, iColumn+1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow-1, iColumn+1];
            media =+ matriz[jRow+1, iColumn];
            if (matriz[jRow, iColumn] < media) {
                menor++;
            }
            else if (matriz[jRow, iColumn] > media) {
                mayor++;
            }
            else if (matriz[jRow, iColumn] == media) {
                igual++;

            }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: No sé como hacerlo, alguna ayuda. Gracias

Comment: La media se calcula sumando todos los valores y dividiendo por la cantidad de valores.

Comment: Sé como se calcula la media, me refería a ir calculando la media de los vecinos mientrás se recorre la matriz.

Comment: Y que has intentado? porque en tu código solo veo como rellenarla

Comment: @Fid ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿No sabes recorrer la matriz o no sabes extraer valores vecinos?

Comment: @Fid los vecinos cuáles serían digamos (i, j) 1,1 tienes que mirar el 1,2 o también los de abajo 2,1? así sucesivamente?

Answer (score 0):

Los vecinos de una celda se corresponden a un desplazamiento en vertical y horizontal:

| Offsets |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h: `-1` v: `-1` | h: `0` v: `-1` | h: `1` v: `-1` |
| h: `-1` v: `0` | h: `0` v: `0` | h: `1` v: `0` |
| h: `-1` v: `1` | h: `0` v: `1` | h: `1` v: `1` |

Crea un objeto para almacenar coordenadas:

```
struct Coordenada
{
    int x, y;
};
```

Con el objeto `Coordenada` puedes redactar una función que calcule la media de un celda:

```
template <auto FILAS, auto COLUMNAS>
int media_vecinos(const int (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS], const Coordenada &coordenada)
{
    static const Coordenada offsets[] =
    {
        {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1},
        {-1,  0},          {1,  0},
        {-1,  1}, {0,  1}, {1,  1},
    };

    int vecinos = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    for (const auto &offset : offsets)
    {
        Coordenada vecino{offset.x + coordenada.x, offset.y + coordenada.y};
        if (vecino.x >= 0 && vecino.x < COLUMNAS && vecino.y >= 0 && vecino.y < FILAS)
        {
            ++vecinos;
            suma += matriz[vecino.y][vecino.x];
        }
    }

    return suma / vecinos;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNta9swEP4s/4obAyfGShd5zV6SOFAKhUHXfij75JkhFLsYYjnYcrBn/NeXnSTbTduQl8vzPCfdPXcWx@NCHLh8Pp8/ZlIc6n0C26yoVJnwfOc4GNRCwW1RlPtE8j13OodkUkFDod04/cZxVJIfD1xhHq9VAXc/7m@eKJj49vH@18@Hm6edo1PyZJ/xP6dEZLKo5qKQlQKNz92cqzL760UmN47GtJiCVb1cD66YYk/XUimuMvFeV6RplagqiiF0COpIt2AUFqyn0C3HYEBGFpYITq9uQCZ2zIUxF0yu9sBYMnQGISw3FqnqnA9/06KEoWdjjWsLhPVYqWfLvGjBntdZ/qoBH156v0L/B6J9TbRYDyFZCnObj4k7LAFcFyZgO03mAm7f6lrUmYl42gL8EN8fetRXENOdH4KdXjRmxWPUxFrWo0NoUJmoupTWkU8wHYOUWQ2eybk37lYerWJ8Q0eWlDBKAko@U3KtJ0FWlHyh5Csl3yj5bhCmRahiKGOoY1bIUMlQylDLUMysOkB1oM9EdYDq4Br6YVrSXtuZgZp5abQ1A8SfDyGsNuD7rbZjohtLNxPdaJrICH1ocPnebH2Om6Mfnd6bLrlcihT3QQ6b8I48IZma0yu1X69FUSvYbuGkv2Yw02a/Ima/pQYv3MdF7M/nfyI98OfqvEB1KHw/4P8B)</kbd>.